# Instance object with a array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, instance

I'm working in c++ with a class like :

```
class foo {
int a ;
    foo (){
      a = rand();
    } 
    foo(int b){ a=b }
 };
 int main(){
   foo * array = new foo[10]; //i want to call constructor foo(int b)
  // foo * array = new foo(4)[10]; ????
 }
```

Please any help , thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first correct your syntax (put `;`, make your constructors `public` etc). Then, you can use uniform initialization in C++11, like

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
    int a;
    foo () {
    }
    foo(int b) { a = b; }
};
int main() 
{
    foo * array = new foo[10] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::cout << array[2].a << std::endl; // ok, displays 2
    delete[] array;
}
```

You should try avoiding altogether raw arrays, use `std::vector` (or `std::array`), or any other standard container instead. Example:

```
std::vector<foo> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

or

```
std::vector v(10, 4); // 10 elements, all initialized with 4
```

No need do remember to delete memory etc.

Comment: ideally with a std::vector though, or a std::array at least.

Comment: I think he wanted to initialize each element to `4`, so the vector example would be: `vector<foo> v(10, foo(4))`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 indeed, if that was the intention. Or just `std::vector<foo> v(10, 4);`, as `foo` ctor is not explicit.

Comment: thanks for the answers , i wanted to initialize my array calling the other contructror (foo(int b) ),  i will try working with std::vector

Comment: @margot that is the case here, it will call the `foo(int)` constructor.